# simple example of tensorflow custom estimator

Tags: tensorflow

How do I write a simple working example of a custom tensorflow estimator using some mock test data? I'm planning to test something with `eval_ops` in the evaluation mode, but I'm missing something with the setup. This code

```
import unittest
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


NFEATS = 5


def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=NFEATS)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    logits = model(features['dense_input'])
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true=labels, y_pred=logits)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=None, evaluation_hooks=None
    )


class TestEstimator(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.N = 1000
        self.batch_size = 100
        self.X = np.random.rand(self.N, NFEATS)
        self.Y = np.random.rand(self.N, 1)

    def test_estimator(self):
        def input_fn():
            data = {
                'X': self.X,
                'Y': self.Y
            }

            def map_fn(dd):
                return ({'dense_input': dd['X']}, dd['Y'])

            dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data) \
                     .map(map_fn).repeat(1).batch(self.batch_size)
            return dset

        estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)
        estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn, steps=3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

produces a long stack trace, to the effect of it is trying to reshape my batch size of 100 into something of size 1

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_estimator (test.test_wis_total_label.TestEstimator)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 100 values, but the requested shape has 1
     [[{{node Reshape}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.316s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tensorflow 2.1

```
import unittest
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


NFEATS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 100


def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(NFEATS,), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    logits = model(features['dense_input'])
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true=labels, y_pred=logits))
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=None, evaluation_hooks=None
    )


class TestEstimator(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.N = 1000
        self.X = np.random.rand(self.N, NFEATS)
        self.Y = np.random.rand(self.N, 1)

    def test_estimator(self):
        def input_fn():
            data = {
                'X': self.X,
                'Y': self.Y
            }

            def map_fn(dd):
                return ({'dense_input': dd['X']}, dd['Y'])

            dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data) \
                     .map(map_fn).repeat(1).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
            return dset

        estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)
        estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn, steps=3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Add batch size to tf.keras.Input and reduce mean of the loss.

Comment: I didn't have to add batch size, just doing the 

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true=labels, y_pred=logits))

 worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see, I have the wrong shape for the tensors going into the mean squared error loss, this works if I do

```
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true=tf.reshape(labels, [-1]), y_pred=tf.reshape(logits, [-1]))
```

Definitely open to simpler examples :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my computer, which uses Tensorflow 1.14, and your test passed after one small change from:

```
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true=labels, y_pred=logits)
```

to:

```
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, logits)
```